# Problem with getting the correct player output

Tags: c++

i was creating a tictactoe game and for the player vs player feature of the game I cant seem to wrap my head around getting the player symbols the correct way around.

I'm not really able to provide the minimum amount of code, as it would be my entire program, so I have grabbed the function. I belive it is something to do with the conditional operator but cant figure out what.
but some guy provided a compilable example for me :)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/* MOCK */
void print() {};
bool win() { return false; };
bool tie() { return false; };
void player_move() {};
void player_move2() {};

char player, player2;
std::string playerName, player2Name;
/********/

void pvp() {
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Player 1 Name:  ";
        std::cin >> playerName;
        std::cout << "Player 2 Name: ";
        std::cin >> player2Name;
        std::cout << "Which symbol (Player 1: X or player 2: O) goes first? ";
        std::cin >> player;
        if (player == 'X' || player == 'O') {
            break;
        }
    }
    player2 = player == 'O' ? 'X' : 'O';
    if (player == 'O') {
        player_move2();
    }
    print();
    while (true) {
        std::cout << playerName << "'s turn to make a move\n";
        player_move();
        print();
        if (win()) {
            std::cout << playerName << " wins!\n";
            return;
        } else if (tie()) {
            std::cout << "Tie!\n";
            return;
        }
        std::cout << player2Name << "'s turn to make a move\n";
        player_move2();
        print();
        if (win()) {
            std::cout << player2Name << " wins!\n";
            return;
        } else if (tie()) {
            std::cout << "Tie!\n";
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    pvp();
}
```

Comment: Your input validation is very user unfriendly. I mean if they type something different from X or O they have to type their names again. Also it will go very wrong if they type their full name. Instead of just bob or sam. Remember `std::cin >> playerName;` stops reading on the first white space character typed. So If Jon Doe was typed the first players name would be "John" the second players name would be "Doe"

Comment: You code does not take advantage of Object Oriented principles. You should probably have classes for player, board, game, etc. The player class should maintain its letter (X or O), its name, etc.

Comment: One point to fix is get the input of the names out of the while loop.

Comment: "getting the player symbols the correct way around" - what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: the order of the conditional opperator such as 'X'? 'O' : 'X'. though if you find that the problem is else where, don't worry about it.

Comment: @MayhemDaes This doesn't answer my question at all. Can you show us some output of your program please? It may seem obvious to you, but from an external perspective it's not that easy to understand where the problem is. _If you are unsure about what you should post_: I encourage you to use your program, use it the way you think it should be fine, but isn't. Additionally add some info on where the differences between the program output and your expectations are.

Comment: this is the result i get when running the program: Player 1 Name:  sayem
Player 2 Name: nabil,    
Which symbol (Player 1: X or player 2: O) goes first? O,    

sayem's turn to make a move,    
Enter an empty cell (1 - 9): 1,

 player 1 is then made the O symbol, instead of saying that it is player 2's turn.

Comment: @MayhemDaes please add these __vital__ information to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

### EXPLANATION

There are some patterns in your code, e.g. "making a move":

```cpp
std::cout << playerName << "'s turn to make a move\n";
player_move();
print();
if (win()) {
    std::cout << playerName << " wins!\n";
    return;
} else if (tie()) {
    std::cout << "Tie!\n";
    return;
}
```

Which is the same for player 1 and player 2, except that you call player2_move(), and display the name of player 2.

Your second loop can then be simplified as

```
while(true) {
    // do_player1_move
    // do_player2_move
}
```

You now come about the problem that the loop will always begin with player 1. To solve this, you're trying to `do_player2_move` before the loop, if player 2 shall start.

```
if (player == 'O') { 
    // do_player2_move
}
while(true) {
    // do_player1_move
    // do_player2_move
}
```

However, in your code you only call `player2_move()`, instead of the entire pattern "making a move" for player 2.

### SOLUTION

Therefore, adjusting

```cpp
if (player == 'O') {
    player_move2();
}
```

to

```cpp
if (player == 'O') {
    std::cout << player2Name << "'s turn to make a move\n";
    player_move2();
    print();
    if (win()) {
        std::cout << player2Name << " wins!\n";
        return;
    } else if (tie()) {
        std::cout << "Tie!\n";
        return;
    }
}
```

should solve your problem